# How to get the date from and to fields of filter in prestashop controller

Tags: search, controller, prestashop

I want get the date from and date to field, selected in date filter search. Need these fields to get PDF report sorted on search filed bases.

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look at some of the core stats* modules, where this is automatically supported.